# Creating a transparent shape within another shape

Tags: android, android-xml, android-resources

Sorry if this is a very simple question; I'm still new to a lot of Android and am learning as I go!

I currently have a shape specified in the drawable folder for a black rectangle at 60% opacity that takes up all of the screen- it creates something of a "tinted window" effect when placed over a picture.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/tinting_rectangle">
    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#ff207d94" />
    <padding android:left="2dp"
        android:top="2dp"
        android:right="2dp"
        android:bottom="2dp" />
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
    <solid android:color="#99000000" />
</shape>
```

My goal, however, is to create a circular "opening" in this tinting, right in the middle of the rectangle. Basically, a transparent oval that allows you to see past the tinting in that one spot to see the background underneath.

I had imagined it would be something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/tinting_rectangle">
            <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#ff207d94" />
            <padding android:left="2dp"
                android:top="2dp"
                android:right="2dp"
                android:bottom="2dp" />
            <corners android:radius="5dp" />
            <solid android:color="#99000000" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#00FFFFFF" />
            <padding 
                android:left="@dimen/tint_padding" 
                android:top="@dimen/tint_padding" 
                android:right="@dimen/tint_padding" 
                android:bottom="@dimen/tint_padding" /> 
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

However, that did not accomplish the goal I was looking for; I still just have a giant solid rectangle of 60% opacity black.

Does anyone have a suggestion for what might accomplish this in XML (looking to keep this as a nodpi solution if possible)? A "tinted window" rectangle with a hole in the middle to see through to whatever is behind it.

Thank you!

EDIT: Additional: As you can see the oval in the second example I am using static padding to center it in the rectangle. Obviously this won't work. If anyone has a good suggestion how to make sure the oval is always centered in the rectangle, that would also be greatly appreciated!